# my sql query logical error and node.js way to work

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

There is a table named "absentTeachers" in sql with only one column i.e. name.
I want to add a name to the table if and only if it doesn't already exists, Can someone please give me a query for the same.

And another problem is I have a array of names in my client side JS, I wanted to add those names in the same table so mainly I wanted to know about an efficient way to do this. I was trying something like this which is not even working.

NODE JS CODE TO ADD RECORDS :

```
app.get('/DataATT-:data', function (req, res) { // UPDATE DATA IN ABSENT TEACHER TABLE
var TeacherName = req.params.data.toString();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'tiger',
    database: 'test'
});

var query = "INSERT INTO absentTeachers (name) SELECT '" + TeacherName + "' FROM absentTeachers WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM absentTeachers WHERE name='" + TeacherName + "')";

console.log(query);
connection.connect();

connection.query(query, function (err, rows, fields) {
    if(err) res.status(500).send(err.toString());

    res.send("Added Teacher " + TeacherName + " to absent Teacher Data");
});

connection.end();
}); // use minus to diff. between tableName and data to add
```

CLIENT SIDE CODE TO SEND XML REQUEST TO SERVER: 
(worst thing I've ever tried, also I want to know if it can work this way.)

```
var Request = [];
var object = [];
```

// pastValues stand for the teachers' names  array I wanted to add from.

```
for(var i = 0; i < pastValues.length; i++){
    var tempRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    Request.push(tempRequest);
}

for(var i = 0; i < Request.length; i++){
    Request[i].onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(Request[i].readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){

            if(Request[i].status === 200){
                console.log('Completed Request ' + i +'.');
            }

        }
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < pastValues.length; i++){ 
    Request[i].open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/updateDataATT-' + pastValues[i], true);
    Request[i].send(null);
}
```

Remember I am not a hardcoder programmer or software developer, I am in high school for now.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Post two questions if you have two separate problems.
The answer to your SQL question can be found with a unbelievably simple google search: http://www.google.com/?q=sql+insert+unique

Comment: **but I tried that unbelievably simple google search It didn't worked. :(**

Comment: how could that not work? As I said before: you have two completely separate problems. Please open two different questions so they can be solved seperately.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thank you, I'm sorry.